# How to install a library in a virtualenv when its link is broken in pip

Tags: python, pip, odoo, virtualenv, pychart

So I want to install openerp 7.0.406 that require pychart and the only link for it seems broken in pip.

```
No distributions at all found for pychart in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from openerp-core==7.0.406->-r picdyn_openerp_conf/requirements (line 11))
```

In the log we have :

```
URLs to search for versions for pychart in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from openerp-core==7.0.406->-r picdyn_openerp_conf/requirements (line 15)):
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/pychart/
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pychart/
  Skipping link http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Yasushi_Saito/pychart (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pychart/); not a file
Not searching http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Yasushi_Saito/pychart (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pychart/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pychart in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from openerp-core==7.0.406->-r picdyn_openerp_conf/requirements (line 15))
```

When you check the uri it return a 404 not found. So I downloaded pychart from somewhere else (http://download.gna.org/pychart/), and I tried to install it (being in my virtualenv).

```
pip install PyChart-1.39.tar.gz 
Installing collected packages: PyChart
  Running setup.py install for PyChart
Successfully installed PyChart
```

It seem, it's not really working because when i try again to update from my requirements file, pip still try to access  "http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Yasushi_Saito/pychart" with the same error message and openerp fail to install.

But when i try to reinstall pychart, it says pychart is in fact installed :

```
pip install PyChart-1.39
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyChart==1.39 from file:///home/pierre/PyChart-1.39 in ./env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is pychart installed or is there a problem with the dependancies of openerp ? Is PyChart different from pychart for pip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you use `--allow-external` and `--allow-unverified` in order to install from an external source.

But there is no `--allow-all-unverified` so as I had several problems (`pychart`, `pyxml`, `openerp-core`) I added them one by one. I was still searching for a way to allow multiple unverified... (`--allow-unverified a b`, `"a b"`, or `a,b` don't work).

But as Adrian Merrall said it's a lot cleaner to add the full URL in *requirements.txt* instead of `PyChart==1.39`:

```
http://download.gna.org/pychart/PyChart-1.39.tar.gz
```

Because you don't even need the `--allow-external` or `--allow-unverified` options and you don't need to treat Pychart differently.

Answer (score 6):

You can try, changing the requirement replacing the invalid `PyChart` with `Python-Chart` in your `requirements.txt`:

> Python-Chart==1.39

It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that it isn't in pypi for some reason.  To install it run

```
pip install http://download.gna.org/pychart/PyChart-1.39.tar.gz
```

If you want to clean up what you have first use pip uninstall

Comment: I tried it and it seems Pychart is installed. Because a pip freeze give "PyChart==1.39". I still have the same error though.

Comment: I re-read your post "when I try again to update from my requirements file".  You should define it in your requirements file as "http://download.gna.org/pychart/PyChart-1.39.tar.gz" instead of "PyChart==1.39"

Comment: Careful with the formatting of stackoverflow, it does not work without the "http://"